# Android: having stack trace error after using sharedprefs for login session

Tags: android, authentication, stack, stack-trace, logout

First I wanted the user to login and once login it wont go back to login screen until logout. So i added sharedPrefs. I was able to play around login>mainActivity then exit the app and open the app it would open mainActivity instead of login screen. Next I would logout and it would go back to login screen. As soon as I am in login screen I would exit the app and reopen the icon app and it would give an error. Another thing is when logout into the login screen and i press cancel button it would also give an error. I must have messed up the stack around but couldn't find the solution. I included the logcat below which shows the part where i could not login anymore.

Login.java

```
public class Login extends Activity {
    //protected static final SharedPreferences settings = null;
    private EditText etUsername;
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Button btnCancel;
    private TextView lblResult;
    private String username;

    @Override  
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
    {  
        //replaces the default 'Back' button action  
        if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)  
        {  
            this.startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,Login.class));  
        }  
        return true;  
    }  
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("username", username);


        if(prefs.getString("username", null)!=null)
        {Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Customer.class); 
        startActivity(i);}

        etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        btnCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
        lblResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            //@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // Check Login
            String username = etUsername.getText().toString();


            if(username.equals("1111")){
                lblResult.setText("Login successful.");


                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Customer.class);
                startActivity(i);
btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // Close the application
            finish();
```

Logout.java

```
public class LogoutActivity extends Activity {
    private Button btnLogout;
    private Button btnCancel;
    private TextView lblResult;
    private EditText code;
    @Override  
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
    {  
        //replaces the default 'Back' button action  
        if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)  
        {  
             this.startActivity(new Intent(LogoutActivity.this,Customer.class));  
        }  
        return true;  
    }  

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.logout);

        code = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.codeout);
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        lblResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String logout = code.getText().toString();



                if (logout.equals("99")){
                    lblResult.setText("Logout successful");

                    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.remove("username");

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    finish();

                } else {
                    lblResult.setText("Logout failed");     
                }}});        
         btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Customer.class);
                startActivity(i);
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Login"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 .............            
        <activity android:name=".LogoutActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="Logout"></activity>
```

Customer.java

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Customer extends ListActivity
{

    @Override  
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
    {  
        //replaces the default 'Back' button action  
        if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)  
        {  
            this.startActivity(new Intent(Customer.this,Customer.class));  
        }  
        return true;  
    }  
    TextView selection;
    CustomerListItem[] items = { 
            new CustomerListItem("Start Trip", StartTripActivity.class), 
            new CustomerListItem("Clock in", ClockinActivity.class), 
            new CustomerListItem("Customer Svc", CustomerSvcActivity.class), 
            new CustomerListItem("Independent Inspection", InspectionActivity.class), 
            new CustomerListItem("Pick Up", PickUpActivity.class), 
            new CustomerListItem("Log Out", LogoutActivity.class)};
    private TextView resultsTxt;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.customer);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CustomerListItem>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
        selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selection);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, items[position].getActivity());
        startActivityForResult(intent, position);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
                switch (requestCode)
            {
                case 0:
                    // TODO: handle the return of the StartTripActivity
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // TODO: handle the return of the ClockinActivity
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // TODO: handle the return of the CustomerSvcActivity
                case 3:
                    // TODO: handle the return of the InspectionActivity
                    break;
                case 4:
                    // TODO: handle the return of the PickUpActivity
                    break;
                case 5:
                    // TODO: handle the return of the LogoutActivity
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            resultsTxt.setText("Canceled");
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
 06-02 07:01:16.981: DEBUG/dalvikvm(981): GC freed 4479 objects / 199288 bytes in 104ms
06-02 07:01:20.632: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(2878): Bad keycharmap - filesize=32
06-02 07:01:20.632: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(2878): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/qtouch-touchscreen.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.0.devname='qtouch-touchscreen'
06-02 07:01:20.632: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(2878): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
06-02 07:01:25.362: DEBUG/DispatchService(946): Handled message = TIMED_SERVICE_UNMASK
06-02 07:01:26.281: INFO/ActivityManager(900): Starting activity: Intent { comp={com.merrill2/com.merrill2.Customer} }
06-02 07:01:26.621: DEBUG/dalvikvm(959): GC freed 1008 objects / 58176 bytes in 180ms
06-02 07:01:26.681: INFO/ActivityManager(900): Displayed activity com.errill2/.Customer: 399 ms
06-02 07:01:30.121: DEBUG/DispatchService(946): Handled message = TIMED_SERVICE_UNMASK
06-02 07:01:38.941: INFO/ActivityManager(900): Starting activity: Intent { comp={com.merrill2/com.merrill2.LogoutActivity} }
06-02 07:01:39.281: INFO/ActivityManager(900): Displayed activity com.merrill2/.LogoutActivity: 330 ms
06-02 07:01:43.071: INFO/ActivityManager(900): Starting activity: Intent { comp={com.merrill2/com.merrill2.Login} }
06-02 07:01:43.631: DEBUG/OpenSSLSessionImpl(900): Freeing OpenSSL session
06-02 07:01:43.640: DEBUG/dalvikvm(900): GC freed 23770 objects / 1125392 bytes in 299ms
06-02 07:01:43.681: INFO/ActivityManager(900): Displayed activity com.merrill2/.Login: 606 ms
06-02 07:01:45.601: INFO/ActivityManager(900): Starting activity: Intent { action=android.intent.action.MAIN categories={android.intent.category.HOME} flags=0x10200000 comp={com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher.Launcher} }
06-02 07:01:45.781: WARN/IInputConnectionWrapper(2878): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
06-02 07:01:47.475: INFO/ActivityManager(900): Starting activity: Intent { action=android.intent.action.MAIN categories={android.intent.category.LAUNCHER} flags=0x10200000 comp={com.merrill2/com.merrill2.Login} }
06-02 07:01:47.501: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2878): Shutting down VM
06-02 07:01:47.501: WARN/dalvikvm(2878): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40013140)
06-02 07:01:47.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2878): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-02 07:01:47.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2878): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=5, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.merrill2/com.merrill2.Customer}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-02 07:01:47.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2878):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3026)
06-02 07:01:47.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2878):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3068)
06-02 07:01:47.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2878):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:128)
06-02 07:01:47.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2878):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1739)
06-02 07:01:47.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2878):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-02 07:01:47.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2878):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-02 07:01:47.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2878):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3992)
06-02 07:01:47.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2878):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 07:01:47.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2878):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-02 07:01:47.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2878):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
06-02 07:01:47.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2878):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
06-02 07:01:47.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2878):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-02 07:01:47.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2878): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-02 07:01:47.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2878):     at com.merrill2.Customer.onActivityResult(Customer.java:90)
06-02 07:01:47.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2878):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3595)
06-02 07:01:47.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2878):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3022)
06-02 07:01:47.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2878):     ... 11 more
06-02 07:01:47.531: INFO/Process(900): Sending signal. PID: 2878 SIG: 3
06-02 07:01:47.551: INFO/dalvikvm(2878): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
06-02 07:01:47.571: INFO/dalvikvm(2878): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-02 07:01:50.482: INFO/Process(2878): Sending signal. PID: 2878 SIG: 9
06-02 07:01:50.501: INFO/ActivityManager(900): Process com.merrill2 (pid 2878) has died.
06-02 07:01:50.501: INFO/WindowManager(900): WIN DEATH: Window{437941d8 com.merrill2/com.merrill2.Customer paused=false}
06-02 07:01:50.501: INFO/WindowManager(900): WIN DEATH: Window{43877980 com.merrill2/com.merrill2.Login paused=true}
06-02 07:01:50.561: WARN/InputManagerService(900): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@435e6fe8
06-02 07:01:54.363: DEBUG/DispatchService(946): Handled message = TIMED_SERVICE_UNMASK
06-02 07:01:55.740: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1225): GC freed 315 objects / 13368 bytes in 90ms
```

Debug Logcat

```
06-02 07:57:53.868: INFO/ActivityManager(900): Starting activity: Intent { comp={com.merrill2/com.merrill2.LogoutActivity} }
06-02 07:57:54.228: INFO/ActivityManager(900): Displayed activity com.merrill2/.LogoutActivity: 360 ms
06-02 07:57:56.968: DEBUG/dalvikvm(959): GC freed 985 objects / 56696 bytes in 86ms
06-02 07:57:57.669: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(2895): Bad keycharmap - filesize=32
06-02 07:57:57.669: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(2895): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/qtouch-touchscreen.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.0.devname='qtouch-touchscreen'
06-02 07:57:57.669: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(2895): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
06-02 07:57:58.628: INFO/ActivityManager(900): Starting activity: Intent { comp={com.merrill2/com.merrill2.Login} }
06-02 07:57:58.768: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2895): GC freed 1710 objects / 109536 bytes in 87ms
06-02 07:57:59.118: INFO/ActivityManager(900): Displayed activity com.merrill2/.Login: 493 ms
06-02 07:58:02.565: DEBUG/DispatchService(946): Handled message = TIMED_SERVICE_UNMASK
06-02 07:58:05.438: INFO/ActivityManager(900): Starting activity: Intent { action=android.intent.action.MAIN categories={android.intent.category.HOME} flags=0x10200000 comp={com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher.Launcher} }
06-02 07:58:05.668: WARN/IInputConnectionWrapper(2895): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
06-02 07:58:06.568: INFO/ActivityManager(900): Starting activity: Intent { action=android.intent.action.MAIN categories={android.intent.category.LAUNCHER} flags=0x10200000 comp={com.merrill2/com.merrill2.Login} }
06-02 07:58:06.588: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2895): Shutting down VM
06-02 07:58:06.588: WARN/dalvikvm(2895): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40013140)
06-02 07:58:06.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2895): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-02 07:58:06.598: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2895): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=5, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.merrill2/com.merrill2.Customer}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-02 07:58:06.598: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3026)
06-02 07:58:06.598: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3068)
06-02 07:58:06.598: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:128)
06-02 07:58:06.598: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1739)
06-02 07:58:06.598: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-02 07:58:06.598: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-02 07:58:06.598: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3992)
06-02 07:58:06.598: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 07:58:06.598: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-02 07:58:06.598: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
06-02 07:58:06.598: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
06-02 07:58:06.598: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-02 07:58:06.598: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2895): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-02 07:58:06.598: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at com.merrill2.Customer.onActivityResult(Customer.java:90)
06-02 07:58:06.598: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3595)
06-02 07:58:06.598: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3022)
06-02 07:58:06.598: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2895):     ... 11 more
06-02 07:58:06.638: INFO/Process(900): Sending signal. PID: 2895 SIG: 3
06-02 07:58:06.638: INFO/dalvikvm(2895): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
06-02 07:58:06.668: INFO/dalvikvm(2895): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-02 07:58:08.600: INFO/Process(2895): Sending signal. PID: 2895 SIG: 9
06-02 07:58:08.618: INFO/ActivityManager(900): Process com.merrill2 (pid 2895) has died.
06-02 07:58:08.628: INFO/WindowManager(900): WIN DEATH: Window{43748a70 com.merrill2/com.merrill2.Customer paused=false}
06-02 07:58:08.638: INFO/ActivityManager(900): Start proc com.merrill2 for activity com.merrill2/.Customer: pid=2932 uid=10053 gids={1006, 3003}
06-02 07:58:08.698: INFO/jdwp(2932): received file descriptor 10 from ADB
06-02 07:58:08.718: WARN/System.err(2932): Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler defined
06-02 07:58:08.728: WARN/System.err(2932): Can't dispatch DDM chunk 4d505251: no handler defined
06-02 07:58:08.918: DEBUG/dalvikvm(900): threadid=13: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
06-02 07:58:08.918: DEBUG/dalvikvm(900): GC freed 24573 objects / 1334712 bytes in 275ms
06-02 07:58:08.938: INFO/WindowManager(900): WIN DEATH: Window{4368b128 com.merrill2/com.merrill2.Login paused=true}
06-02 07:58:09.178: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2932): Shutting down VM
06-02 07:58:09.178: WARN/dalvikvm(2932): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40013140)
06-02 07:58:09.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.merrill2/com.merrill2.Customer}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=5, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.merrill2/com.merrill2.Customer}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2668)
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:128)
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1710)
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3992)
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=5, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.merrill2/com.merrill2.Customer}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3026)
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2637)
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932):     ... 12 more
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at com.merrill2.Customer.onActivityResult(Customer.java:90)
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3595)
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3022)
06-02 07:58:09.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2932):     ... 13 more
06-02 07:58:09.228: INFO/Process(900): Sending signal. PID: 2932 SIG: 3
06-02 07:58:09.228: INFO/dalvikvm(2932): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
06-02 07:58:09.248: INFO/dalvikvm(2932): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-02 07:58:12.538: DEBUG/DispatchService(946): Handled message = TIMED_SERVICE_UNMASK
06-02 07:58:16.577: WARN/ActivityManager(900): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
06-02 07:58:18.971: WARN/ActivityManager(900): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{43610e18 {com.merrill2/com.merrill2.Customer}}
06-02 07:58:24.058: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1225): GC freed 270 objects / 10200 bytes in 90ms
06-02 07:58:29.088: DEBUG/dalvikvm(981): GC freed 688 objects / 28808 bytes in 112ms
06-02 07:59:01.598: DEBUG/PowerManagerService(900): setPowerState: mPowerState=3 newState=1 noChangeLights=false
```

Comment: Error has occured in Customer class could you please post your Customer class code and related XML layout.

Comment: whoops I fixed the customer class error I updated it with the new logcat error that shows the logout/login stack problem. Logout>login screen exit app and reopen the app it gives error(same with cancel button in login screen)

Comment: I do not see where you initialise your resultsTxt. Have you tried debugging your application?

Comment: I think I will delete resultsTxt as I dont seem to need it in Customer class but I felt like without it it would give an error. As for the debug, I just updated a debug error. Showed the logout and into login screen and exit app then open app given an error.

Comment: Well it still says that the root of your troubles lies in `at com.merrill2.Customer.onActivityResult(Customer.java:90)`. I would just put a breakpoint inside onActivityResult and step line by line while checking variables content.

Comment: Im wondering how can customer class affect opening login screen?

Comment: Well it can be a stack thing, when you try to start activity without proper flags, it can actually be bringing in last stack activity to the front instead of the activity you try to start. Either way I would just fix Customer bug first and then see how it affects whole application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is resultsTxt, As you are not initialising it and trying to call .setText method on it. Try to initialise and check does everything work as you want.

how to :

```
resultsTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.**Here select text view where you want to show your result text**);
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Im assuming that shouldn't have caused the stack trace error.

Comment: Error is nullpointerexception, yes? However LuxuryMode's answer is worth checking as he/she made a good point!

Comment: i comment the resultsTxt out and its not giving error when i open the app (after logout and exiting the app) like i mentioned in the post. its fixed now thanks

Comment: Glad it worked, However initialise resultsTxt if you really want to use it.

Comment: I dont think i will be using that as it will only show the listview. for future reference can you give me example of how to initialize resultsTxt?

Comment: check your Customer class, you are initialising "selection" in same way you can initialise resultsTxt. check my answer as I have edited it.

Comment: However if you just want to show a cancel message, Make use of "Toast"

Answer (score 1):

From the trace, it appears that you need to have a listview in your XML with an id like this:

`android:id="@android:id/list"`

Comment: In the `Customer` class's XML file.

Comment: @Haphazard and whats on line 44 in your Customer class? ;)

Comment: @LuxuryMode err.. the first call to said mal-referenced list?

Comment: Yup. You're not setting up your `ListView` correctly. Paste your Customer class in your post.

Comment: @LuxuryMode I would if this were my post!

Comment: whoops I fixed the customer class error I updated it with the new logcat error that shows the logout/login stack problem. Logout>login screen exit app and reopen the app it gives error(same with cancel button in login screen)

Comment: @merrill dude, you need to post all your code if you actually want to fix this

Comment: just posted up the customer class =)

Comment: @LuxuryMode do you mean for the manifest.xml? I already have android:id="@android:id/list" under my customer.xml (layout) without that, my customer class wouldn' work the first place.